# Elasticsearch totalHits remains thesame

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch to search for document from my index. But when ever I use, .must and .should in the same query, my totalHits stay unchanged. I need help. the query is below.

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("myindex")
.setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("work_duration")
.gte(tMin).lte(tMax)).must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("DOB").gte(minYear)
.lte(maxYear)).should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("town",town.toLowerCase().trim()))
.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("country",country.toLowerCase().trim()))
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", keyword.toLowerCase().trim())))
.setFrom(0).setSize(167).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Should post an example of your mapping and the data, i.e. a document(s) in your index.

Answer (score 0):

When mixing must and should, should has no meaning for the total result. Either you match, what is required (must), or you don't. Documents, that only match the should clause, cannot be include since they do not match the must clause.
In this case, should is only used to score documents, that also match these clauses, better.